# Android Chat App with XMPP

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, chat

Im trying to Set Up an Android facebook Chat App.
I've implemented the Facebook Login with the Permission for XMPP.

Now if I want just test the basic Connection Settings of my asmack.jar i get this Error

```
12-18 21:29:48.845: E/AndroidRuntime(5516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 21:29:48.845: E/AndroidRuntime(5516): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration
12-18 21:29:48.845: E/AndroidRuntime(5516): at com.example.messenger.MainActivity.testXMPP(MainActivity.java:68)
```

Here is my Code.
I hope somebody can help.
(The Error is caused in the TestXMPP)

```
package com.example.messenger;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    TextView TV1,TV2;
    Button B1,B2;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    B2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);

    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("read_friendlists","xmpp_login"));

    StatusCallback btn_callback = authButton.getSessionStatusCallback();

     B1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         String text3= "asdfasf";

         Session act_session = Session.getActiveSession(); 
         text3 = act_session.getPermissions().get(0)+act_session.getPermissions().get(1);

         TV1.setText(text3);
        }
      });
      B2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                testXMPP();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            TV2.setText(e.toString());
            }
        }
      });

  }

  public void testXMPP()throws XMPPException{

      ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
      config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
      config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
      config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
      config.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
      config.setTruststorePassword("changeit");
      config.setTruststoreType("bks");
    //XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);

  }

  private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";

  private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

      }
  };

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession()
          .onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Something went wrong when you added the library that adds `org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration` to your app. Check your `/libs` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put asmack library in libs folder.

Comment: Hi,now I get Problems with the authentification. It says that I'm not authenticaced.                                                            SASL authentication failed using mechanism X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM: 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:341)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:242)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:371)
at com.example.messenger.ChatActivity.testLogin(ChatActivity.java:240)
at com.example.messenger.ChatActivity.access$0(ChatActivity.java:189)

Comment: I think facebook not use SASL authentication. try it without authentication mechanism.

Comment: same problem. but sending message works if i set permissions via facebook browser (m.facebook.com / facebook app not installed) and not  when i check permissions via native facebook app